# How to get unsigned long long from C++ to Kotlin through JNI?

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, android-ndk

I'd like to read an unsigned long long from my Kotlin code.
The value comes from C++ code through JNI.

Here is the C++ code :

```
unsigned long long getMaxValue() {
    return -1;
}
```

Here is the JNI code :

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_com_tb_of_1ir_MainActivity_getMaxValue(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    static auto a = MyCppSingleton::get();
    return a->getMaxValue();
}
```

And here is the Kotlin code :

```
Toast.makeText(this, "getMaxValue : \"${getMaxValue()}\"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
private external fun getMaxValue(): Long
```

I also tried with BigInteger but with no result...

Thanks !

Comment: Why are you returning a negative number if the return type is `unsigned`?

Comment: It is to get the max value possible for unsigned long long.

Comment: The max value for an unsigned long long is `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max();`.  Second, I suggest you use the C++ types that describe exactly the number of bits and sign type, i.e. `int64_t`, `uint64_t`, etc. instead of `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's more explicit to the compiler I think.

Comment: Java only know signed integers, unsigned won't work here.

Comment: Yes I know that, thanks anyway, but I'm pretty sure there should be mathematical way to do that.

Comment: An `unsigned long long` (assuming it is 64-bit) will, mathematically, be able to be represented in a 128-bit signed type, or if that isn't supported a `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand "or if that isn't supported a BigInteger". Do you mean it is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in a simple way. Maybe by decomposition.